# Не рендерится компонент React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть компонент `TodoList`:

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import styles from './TodoList.module.css';
import TodoItems from "./TodoItems/TodoItems";

function TodoList() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    function addItem(e) {
        let itemArray = items;

        if (inputEl.current.value !== '') {
            itemArray.unshift({
                text: inputEl.current.value,
                key: Date.now()
            });

            setItems(itemArray);

            inputEl.current.value = '';
        }

        console.log(itemArray);

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    const inputEl = useRef(null);

    return (
        <div className={styles.main}>
            <div className={styles.header}>
                <form onSubmit={addItem}>
                    <input ref={inputEl} placeholder='Введите задачу'></input>
                    <button type='submit'>Ок</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <TodoItems entries={items}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TodoList;
```

Который вызывает компонент `TodoItems`:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './TodoItems.module.css';

function TodoItems(props) {
    let todoEntries = props.entries;
    console.log(todoEntries);
    let listItems = todoEntries.map((item) => {
        return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li>;
    });
    console.log(listItems);

    return (
        <div className={styles.main}>
            <ul>
                {listItems}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TodoItems;
```

Но `TodoItems` просто не отображается. Хотел бы получить помощь в данном вопросе. `TodoItems` отобажается только при внесении изменений в код и сохранении.

Update:
Написал классовый компонент, он работает, но не понимаю чем он отличается от функционального.

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './TodoList.module.css';
import TodoItems from "./TodoItems/TodoItems";

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          items: []
        };

        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    }

    addItem(e) {
        let itemArray = this.state.items;

        if (this._inputElement.value !== '') {
            itemArray.unshift({
                text: this._inputElement.value,
                key: Date.now()
            });

            this.setState({
                items: itemArray
            });

            this._inputElement.value = '';
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.main}>
                <div className={styles.header}>
                    <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                        <input ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a} placeholder='Введите задачу'/>
                        <button type='submit'>Ок</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <TodoItems entries={this.state.items}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что он не отображается?
`const [items, setItems] = useState([]);`
`<TodoItems entries={items}/>`
Вы передаете пустой массив. Визуально у вас ничего не отрендерится изначально

Comment: @РоманТатаринов, кажется я обновляю его здесь `setItems(itemArray);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Почему функциональный компонент НЕ работает**

Ваш функциональный компонент не работает как ожидается, потому что вы изменяете массив `items`, который лежит в `useState`, а затем передаёте его же обратно в `setItems`. Поскольку ссылка на массив не изменилась, React считает, что состояние не изменилось (он не сравнивает массив "в глубь"). Чтобы React понял, что он должен инициировать ререндер компонента, нужно передать в `setItems` новый массив.

Для этого вам нужно привести функцию `addItem` к следующему виду

```
function addItem(e) {
  if (inputEl.current.value !== "") {
    setItems([
      {
        text: inputEl.current.value,
        key: Date.now()
      },
      ...items
    ]);

    inputEl.current.value = "";
  }

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Здесь в `setItems` передаётся новый массив, в котором первым элементов вставляется новый элемент, а после него копируются все элементы из массива `items` с помощью трёх точек ([Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax))

**Почему классовый компонент работает**

В классовых компонентах для обновления состояния используется функция `setState`. В отличие от `useState`, она не пытается избежать дополнительных ререндеров, сравнивая новое состояние с предыдущим. `setState` вызывает ререндер компонента безусловно, даже если состояние не было изменено.

Поэтому классовый компонент работает как ожидается, даже не смотря на то, то вы изменяете массив `this.state.items` и передаёте его же в `setState`, не создавая новый массив.